# How Appell-Humbert theorem works in the simplest case of an elliptic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, abelian-varieties

Line bundles on complex tori $V/\Lambda$ could be described by a pair $(H, \chi)$, where $H$ is a hermitian form on $V$ s.t. $\operatorname{Im} H(\Lambda, \Lambda) \subset \mathbb{Z}$, and $\chi$ is a semicharacter i.e. satisfy condition
$$
\chi(\lambda + \mu) = \chi(\lambda) \chi(\mu) \exp( i \pi \operatorname{Im} H(\lambda, \mu)),
$$
for any $\lambda, \mu \in \Lambda$.

Let denote $L(H, \chi)$ the corresponding line bundle of Appell-Humbert theorem.

For simplest case of an elliptic curve $E = V/\Lambda$ and line bundle $L=\mathcal{O}_E(p)$, ($p \in E$ is a divisor consisting of just one point) how to find explicitly pair $(H, \chi)$ for this $L$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, first you need a Hermitian form $H:\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ such that $\Im H(\Lambda\times\Lambda)\subseteq\mathbb{Z}$. Using a little bit of linear algebra, it is easy to see that there is only one $\mbox{mod }\mathbb{Z}$. Explicitly, if $\Lambda=\langle 1,\tau\rangle$ for $\tau\in\mathbb{H}$, then every Hermitian form that satisfies what I just wrote is an integer multiple of
$$H_0:(z,w)\mapsto \frac{z\overline{w}}{\Im\tau}.$$
We see that the map $\chi_0(a+b\tau)=(-1)^{ab\Im H_0(1,\tau)}$ is a semi-character for $H_0$, and actually all of them are of the form
$$\chi_x:a+b\tau\mapsto\chi_0e^{2\pi i\Im H_0(x,\cdot)}$$
for a certain $x\in\mathbb{C}$ (actually we can think of $x\in\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$). In your case, we can write
$$\mathcal{O}_E(p)\simeq L(H_0,\chi_p).$$
Take a look at Birkenhake-Lange, page 48, for example.

**Edit:** We can see this all explicitly as part of the exponential sequence:
$$0\to E\stackrel{i}{\to}\mbox{Pic}(E)\stackrel{c_1}{\to}\mathbb{Z}\to0$$
where $i(x)=L(0,e^{2\pi i\Im H_0(x,\cdot)})$ and $c_1(L(mH_0,\chi))=m$.

Comment: I'm expecting that line bundle with such $H_0$ and $\chi_0$ should have canonical factors equal to the classical factors of one dimensional Riemann theta function, but when I insert this data into formula for canonical factors I get something different. It would be very helpful to me if you show how these canonical factors are related.

Comment: Also exponent $im H_0(1, \tau)$ is surprising, is not it just "-1"?

Comment: What I wrote is ok, but I have to check and see if I'm possibly making some non-trivial identifications (you may have to translate the line bundle by some point so that it corresponds exactly to $\mathcal{O}_E(p)$).

Comment: Yes, what you wrote is fine. I made a mistake and compute canonical factors, but I need to compute classical factors, and classical factors coincide with the factors of Riemann theta function.

Comment: Ok great! If you have any more problems, then try doing what I did above but instead with $\mathcal{O}_E(p)=L(H_0,\chi_{-p})$. I may have cancelled out a - sign somewhere, since translation of $\mathcal{O}_E(\{0\})$ by $p$ is $\mathcal{O}_E(-p)$.

Comment: A priori it does not seem clear to me that $L(H_0,\chi_0)$ in your set-up should give $O_E(O)$ for $O$ the identity of $E$. Is there a reason you make.